# How to check if a Unity app is running on modded Android system?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, cyanogenmod

I have a made, using Unity, an Android mobile app which currently has over a million users. There are various unresolved Crashes. Unfortunately, the stats I receive from Google does not contain enough 
 information to diagnose the problem. I'm concerned about the Android distribution (Is it cyanogen or any other modded android).

Is there a way to check the android version my app is running on and determine if it is modded or not?

Comment: I have tried to improve the question by altering the title and improving the English. I have removed a bit of information which I could not place as it seemed it was a leftover from the writing process. I hope this explains the question in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

SystemInfo should have what you are looking for. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo.html

EDIT: You may also be interested in Application, especially genuineCheckAvailable.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.html